# assert, -NDEBUG and segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, assert

I have quite a large piece of code, that works well in a development version, with many `assert()` in the code. I disabled assertions with `-DNDEBUG` directive passed to g++, and now my code breaks with seg. fault. Is there something I don't know about assert()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most common issue with assert to my knowledge is having code with side effects within the assert itself.  When you compile with -DNDEBUG asserts are essentially commented out, and thus code inside the assert isn't executed.  The assert man page mentions this in the bugs section:

```
BUGS
       assert()  is implemented as a macro; if the expression tested has side-
       effects, program behavior will be different depending on whether NDEBUG
       is defined.  This may create Heisenbugs which go away when debugging is
       turned on.
```

Comment: To resolve that problem, use VERIFY rather than ASSERT for code with side effects, e.g. [see here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/1719/surviving-the-release-version/7/).